# file not found error when trying to include id3lib header

Tags: c++, header, include, id3lib

I downloaded id3lib and placed the directory in my main.cpp directory but both g++ and visual studio give file/directory not founds and "undefined" errors

Here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <id3lib-3.8.3/include/id3/tag.h>
int main() { std::cout << "hi"; }
```

g++ main.cpp gives:

```
main.cpp:2:46: fatal error: id3lib-3.8.3/include/id3/tag.h: No such file or 
directory
 #include <id3lib-3.8.3/include/id3/tag.h>
```

if I use "" instead of <>, i get this error:

```
id3lib-3.8.3/include/id3/tag.h:32:30: fatal error: id3/id3lib_frame.h: No 
such file or directory
 #include <id3/id3lib_frame.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to put it beside your main file. As you can see in your first approach when you used `#include` with `<>` it can't find it, that's because (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)) :

> For `#include <filename>` the preprocessor searches in an implementation
>   dependent manner, normally in search directories pre-designated by the
>   compiler/IDE. This method is normally used to include standard library
>   header files.

You didn't tell your compiler where to look for `id3lib-3.8.3/include/id3/tag.h` so `<>` will not work for you.

Then you tried `""`. it found `id3lib-3.8.3/include/id3/tag.h` but in the `tag.h` there is `#include <id3/id3lib_frame.h>`, So back to problem with first approach, right?

What you need to do is that you need to tell your compiler/IDE where to look for these files. In visual studio click right on your project file, then properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories and add the include library (`$(ProjectDir)id3lib-3.8.3/include/` or maybe `$(SolutionDir)id3lib-3.8.3/include/`) to it. Then your first approach should work fine.

Comment: I added the include directory as you said, and the include line is now #include <id3/tag.h>, but there still is a whole list of errors on VS. The first error is "incomplete type is not allowed" on the file field.h

Comment: @J.W That's another thing, using libraries in c++ can be difficult task sometimes, You need to take care of every dependency. I don't know about `id3lib` but almost every library has it's *how to use/compile* document, read it carefully.

Comment: id3lib says that just #include<id3/tag.h> would work (link: http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/api/index.html). This is weird because I got it to work on g++ the first time around. I moved the directory to a separate drive and updated windows since that time and now it doesn't work.